# Need help getting char and int data from file

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that takes a text file with results of an ad campaign and need to  find the average rating of the campaign for 4 different demographics. I think I have it all figured out just struggling with getting the data from the file and into char and int variables. Do I need to read it all as strings and then convert or can I read them into those variables?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
//declare vars
ifstream fileIn;
string path;
string name;
char yn;
int age;
double rating;
double rate1 = 0;
double rate1Count = 0;
double avg1 = 0;
double rate2 = 0;
double rate2Count = 0;
double avg2 = 0;
double rate3 = 0;
double rate3Count = 0;
double avg3 = 0;
double rate4 = 0;
double rate4Count = 0;
double avg4 = 0;
double totalAvg = 0;

cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

// prompt user
cout << "Please enter a path to the text file with results: ";

// get path
cin >> path;
cout << endl;

// open a file for input
fileIn.open(path);

// error message for bad file
if (!fileIn.is_open()){
    cout << "Unable to open file." << endl;
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

// read and echo to screen
cout << ifstream(path);

// restore the file
fileIn.clear();
fileIn.seekg(0);
cout << endl << endl;

// get average for demos

while (!fileIn.eof){
    fileIn >> name;
    fileIn >> yn;
    fileIn >> age;
    fileIn >> rating;

    if (yn != 121 && age < 18){
        rate1 += rating; 
        rate1Count++;
    }
    if (yn == 121 && age < 18){
        rate2 += rating;
        rate2Count++;
    }
    if (yn != 121 && age >= 18){
        rate3 += rating;
        rate3Count++;
    }
    if (yn == 121 && age >= 18){
        rate4 += rating;
        rate4Count++;
    }

}

avg1 = rate1 / rate1Count;
avg2 = rate2 / rate2Count;
avg3 = rate3 / rate3Count;
avg4 = rate4 / rate4Count;

cout << yn << age << rating;



// pause and exit
getchar();
getchar();
return 0;
```

}

The text file

Bailey           Y 16 68

Harrison         N 17 71

Grant            Y 20 75

Peterson         N 21 69

Hsu              Y 20 79

Bowles           Y 15 75

Anderson         N 33 64

Nguyen           N 16 68

Sharp            N 14 75

Jones            Y 29 75

McMillan         N 19 8

Gabriel          N 20 62

Comment: When you ask a question here you're supposed to say what specific problem you've observed... as is you haven't told us what aspect of your file input isn't working, i.e. what problem you've observed in the data you did manage to read, whether it loops forever or crashes etc..

Answer (score 1):

Ditch the `cout << ifstream(path); ... fileIn.seekg(0);` - that's all unhelpful.

For input, use:

```
while (fileIn >> name >> yn >> age >> rating)
{
    ...
```

That will exit when there's some problem getting the input - whether due to invalid characters for the type (e.g. letters when reading a number), or end-of-file.

> Do I need to read it all as strings and then convert or can I read them into those variables?

As above, you don't need to, but you can get better quality input validation and error messages for the user if you get each complete line as a `string` then attempt to parse out the values:

```
std::string line;
for (int line_num = 1; getline(fileIn, line); ++line_num)
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    if (iss >> name >> yn >> age >> rating >> std::ws &&
        iss.eof())
        ...use the values...
    else
        std::cerr << "bad input on line " << line_num
            << " '" << line << "'\n";
        // could exit or throw if desired...
}
```

Comment: And for the output use `cout << yn << " " << age << " " << rating << std::endl;` so you can understand the output.

Comment: @Riley: we're not mind-readers ;-P... what's *the code* on the line where that error is reported?